# Cocoa (Mac) Core Data with multiple array controllers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

So I'm working on a simple Core Data app, and I've run into a snag.

I've got a Patient entity (with a TableView list of patient names, and then a separate section with various textfields and checkboxes), and it's got a to-many relationship to both a Policy, and PlaceOfService entity.  Both Policy and PlaceOfService are represented by a 2-column TableView.

I am able to add entries to both TableViews, but when I select another patient the values I put into these TableViews persists.  My intention is for each of the Policy and PlaceOfService TableViews to contain information unique to the selected patient.

Note:  I have done this exclusively in the nib, (no code).

Thank you in advance for any assistance.